# Domino R9.0.1 FP4: disable logging related to ImportConvertHeaders?

Tags: lotus-domino, mime

Recently, we installed FP4, and now there are lots of messages on the console. It happens when a mailed document is opened or saved from a browser, using XPages. The rich-text fields in the mail are in MIME format.

Lots of lines appear referring to ImportConvertHeaders, like:

```
 25/06/2015 17:02:38,90 ImportConvertHeaders> Before ParallelList()
 25/06/2015 17:02:38,97 ImportConvertHeaders> SendTo: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2559]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,03 ImportConvertHeaders> After ParallelList()
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,09 ImportConvertHeaders> SendTo: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2575]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,15 ImportConvertHeaders> INetSendTo: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2576]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,22 ImportConvertHeaders> OriginalTo: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2577]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,28 ImportConvertHeaders> Resent_To: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2578]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,34 ImportConvertHeaders> Apparently_To: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2579]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,40 ImportConvertHeaders> AltSendTo: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2580]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,47 ImportConvertHeaders> $StorageTo: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2581]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,53 ImportConvertHeaders> $LangTo: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2582]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,59 ImportConvertHeaders> Before ParallelList()
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,65 ImportConvertHeaders> CopyTo: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2587]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,72 ImportConvertHeaders> After ParallelList()
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,78 ImportConvertHeaders> CopyTo: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2603]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,84 ImportConvertHeaders> Originalcc: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2604]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,90 ImportConvertHeaders> INetCopyTo: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2605]
 25/06/2015 17:02:39,97 ImportConvertHeaders> Resent_cc: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2606]
 25/06/2015 17:02:40,03 ImportConvertHeaders> AltCopyTo: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2607]
 25/06/2015 17:02:40,09 ImportConvertHeaders> $StorageCc: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2608]
 25/06/2015 17:02:40,15 ImportConvertHeaders> $LangCc: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2609]
 25/06/2015 17:02:40,22 ImportConvertHeaders> Before ParallelList()
 25/06/2015 17:02:40,28 ImportConvertHeaders> BlindCopyTo: > [cimpimsg.cpp, 2614]
 25/06/2015 17:02:40,34 ImportConvertHeaders> After ParallelList()
```

Why do these messages appear, and is there any way to get rid of them? We plan to go back to FP3 in case

Comment: Sounds like a logging level got left on "DEBUG" and/or someone at IBM who worked on that particular method didn't clean up after themselves. Probably something they will have to fix. Hope I am wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is solved with [Domino 9.0.1 Fix Pack 4 Interim Fix 1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963) (901FP4HF70)

Comment: I'll take your word for it. ;-)

Comment: I was annoyed by this issue myself and yes, trust me, it's gone with this fix :-)

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `DEBUG_ICAL_ADDRESSES=0` to the server's notes.ini to disable it (as recommended by IBM in this tech note: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21960516)