# Performance drop due to NotesDocument.closeMIMEEntities()

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

After moving my XPages application from one Domino server to another (both version 9.0.1 FP4 and with similar hardware), the application's performance strongly dropped. Benchmarks revealed that the execution of

```
doc.closeMIMEEntities(false,"body")
```

which takes **~0.1ms** on the old server, now on average takes **>10ms** on the new one. This difference wouldn't matter if it was only about a few documents, but when initializing the application I read more than 1000 documents and so the initialization time changes from less than 1sec to more than 10sec.

In the code, I use the line above to close the MIME entity without saving any changes after **reading** from it (**NO writing**). The function always returns true on both servers. Still it now takes **more than 100x longer** despite nothing has been changed in the entity.

The facts that both server computers have more or less the same hardware, and the replicas of my application contain the same design and data on both servers, let me believe that the problem has something to do with the settings of the Domino server.

Can anybody help me with this?

---

PS: I always use `session.setConvertMime(false)` before opening the NotesDocument, i.e. the conversion from MIME to RichText *should* not be what causes the problem.

PPS: The `HTTPJVMMaxHeapSize` is the same on both servers (1024M) and there are multiple 100Mb of free memory. I just mention this in case someone thinks the problem might be related to being out of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is related to the "[ImportConvertHeaders bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31055638/domino-r9-0-1-fp4-disable-logging-related-to-importconvertheaders)" in Domino 9.0.1 FP4. It has already been solved with [Interim Fix 1](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21657963) (as pointed out by @KnutHerrmann [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31921757/1697566)).

It turned out that the old Domino server had Interim Fix 1 installed, while the "new" one had not. After applying the fix to the new Domino server the performance is back to normal and everything works as expected.